# -scroll-mt not applying to 'Testimonials' section

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project with tailwind and I'm trying to add a -scroll-mt on my 'Testimonials' section. I would like my `h2`Testimonials`h2` to have more space off of the top of the browser's edge.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="font-html scroll-smooth">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css" />
    <title>Hero</title>
  </head>
  <body
    class="bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-700 via-gray-600 to-slate-700 dark:bg-gradient-to-r dark:from-gray-900 dark:via-neutral-950 dark:to-slate-900 antialiased text-white min-h-screen text-center"
  >
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <header
      class="relative top-0 z-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-700 via-gray-600 to-slate-700 dark:bg-gradient-to-r dark:from-gray-900 dark:via-neutral-950 dark:to-slate-900 mb-12"
    >
      <section class="flex justify-between items-center p-8 max-w-4xl mx-auto">
        <h1
          class="text-4xl font-bold transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
        >
          <a href="#hero">Manga<span class="text-indigo-300">Verse</span></a>
        </h1>

        <div>
          <button
            id="mobile-btn"
            class="lg:hidden text-3xl font-medium mr-2 focus:outline-none"
          >
            &#9776;
          </button>
          <nav class="hidden lg:block space-x-8 font-medium text-lg">
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="/manga login page/dist/login.html"
              target="_blank"
              >Login</a
            >
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#testimonials"
              >Testimonials</a
            >
            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="/manga subscription cards/dist/sub.html"
              target="_blank"
              >Subsciptions</a
            >

            <a
              class="hover:text-gray-300 inline-block transform hover:scale-105 hover:dark:scale-105 transition-all"
              href="#contact"
              >Contact</a
            >
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
    </header>

    <!-- Hero Section -->

    <main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto">
      <div
        id="hero"
        class="flex items-center justify-center flex-col-reverse lg:flex-row gap-2 -mt-8 lg:mt-28 px-8"
      >
        <article class="lg:w-1/2 text-4xl lg:text-5xl">
          <h2 class="font-bold max-w-4xl">
            Start <span class="text-indigo-300">Your</span> Adventure.
          </h2>
          <br />
          <h2 class="font-bold max-w-4xl">
            <span class="text-indigo-300">Explore</span> the Manga<span
              class="text-indigo-300"
              >Verse</span
            >!
          </h2>
        </article>
        <img
          class="w-[500px] h-auto mb-12 block"
          src="img/newToji.png"
          alt="Toji Fushiguro"
        />
      </div>

      <hr class="w-1/2 mx-auto mt-12" />

      <!-- Testimonials Section -->
      <section class="mt-24 text-4xl lg:text-5xl font-bold space-y-24 -scroll-mt-20"> 

        

        <h2 id="testimonials" class="font-bold">Testimonials</h2>
        <figure class="px-14">
          <blockquote class="bg-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-800 p-8 rounded-2xl">
            <p class="text-2xl italic">
              <q
                >Manga<span class="text-indigo-300">Verse</span> is a manga
                lover's dream come true! With its
                <span class="text-indigo-300">vast collection</span> and
                <span class="text-indigo-300">user-friendly interface</span>,
                it's my go-to destination for
                <span class="text-indigo-300">top-quality manga</span>. Highly
                recommended!</q
              >
            </p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="text-xl italic font-medium mt-6">
            &#8212;Clark Keneth
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="px-14">
          <blockquote class="bg-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-800 p-8 rounded-2xl">
            <p class="text-2xl italic">
              <q
                >This <span class="text-indigo-300">amazing site</span> has
                redefined my manga experience! The
                <span class="text-indigo-300">Library</span> function keeps my
                favorites organized, while
                <span class="text-indigo-300">downloading chapters</span> for
                <span class="text-indigo-300">offline reading</span> is a
                lifesaver. It's convenience and quality rolled into one
                fantastic platform!</q
              >
            </p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="text-xl italic font-medium mt-6">
            &#8212;Adam Smasher
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="px-14">
          <blockquote class="bg-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-800 p-8 rounded-2xl">
            <p class="text-2xl italic">
              <q
                >This place is fantastic!
                <span class="text-indigo-300">Early chapter access</span> keeps
                me engaged, and the
                <span class="text-indigo-300">ad-free experience</span> ensures
                uninterrupted enjoyment. It's my go-to for hassle-free manga
                indulgence!</q
              >
            </p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="text-xl font-medium italic mt-6">
            &#8212;Sarah Clark
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </section>
```

I've tried multiple values but I'm not seeing any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure the scroll margin is applied to the element with the "testimonials" id like so:

```
<section class="mt-24 text-4xl lg:text-5xl font-bold space-y-24"> 
    <h2 id="testimonials" class="font-bold -scroll-mt-20">Testimonials</h2>
        ...
    </h2>
</section>
```

"The `scroll-margin-top` property defines the top margin of the scroll snap area that is used for snapping this box to the snapport." - MDN on [scroll-margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top)

Because you weren't snapping to the element with the scroll margin, no scroll margin was applied.

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/tailwind-scroll-margin-mdc4f5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A76%2C17).